# jQuery Datatables in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have 2 jquery datatables in 2 different menu tabs. When I append the first datatable (id=gvSchedule) it works fine. As soon as I append the second datatable (id=gvMySchedule), it looses formatting and I can't see the pagination or jquery datatable search option. I am sure that the problem is because of the second JavaScript but I haven't succeeded fixing it.

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="tabe-1" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvSchedule" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" HeaderText="CenterName" SortExpression="CenterName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Resource" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="StartTime" SortExpression="StartTime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="EndTime" SortExpression="EndTime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDescription" HeaderText="Event" SortExpression="EventDescription" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View Notes" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!--The problem occurs for this grid-->


<div id="tabe-2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvMySchedule" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="table table-bordered" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CenterName" HeaderText="CenterName" SortExpression="CenterName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Resource" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}" SortExpression="Date" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="StartTime" SortExpression="StartTime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="EndTime" SortExpression="EndTime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDescription" HeaderText="Event" SortExpression="EventDescription" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="View Notes" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=gvSchedule]').prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[id*=gvMySchedule]').prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
        });

    });
</script>
```

Please assist how I can fix the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by using the following script below instead of the 2 JS scripts as shown in the question. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('table').each(function () {
            $(this).prepend($("<thead style=background-color:#ff974d></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:eq(0)"))).DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```